# RXJAVA ROOM android

Tags: android, android-room, rx-android

Trying to learn Room and RXJAVA. 
I have about 80% of this understood but I'm getting stuck on figuring the rest out.

Here is the error I get on the insert data.

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method
>   'void
>   com.example.learnroom.EntityDao.insert(com.example.learnroom.Entitys)'
>   on a null object reference

If I don't run the try catch I get the following error which seems to be related.

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{com.example.learnroom/com.example.learnroom.MainActivity}:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method
>   'io.reactivex.Maybe
>   com.example.learnroom.EntityDao.getEntity(java.lang.String)' on a null
>   object reference

How do I fix this?

I have tried to simplify from the tutorials all over the web most using recyclerviews to just 2 text fields. They say this is 3 pieces but it doesn't seem like it, as the DB was never set up so I ran it in a method to run the code. Maybe someone can help explain to me how this really works.
my code

Dao

```
public interface EntityDao {

 @Query("SELECT * FROM Entitys WHERE ID  = :ID LIMIT 1")
Maybe<List<Entitys>> getEntity(String ID);

@Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
void insert(Entitys entitys);

@Query("DELETE FROM Entitys")
void deleteAllEntity();
}
```

Entity

```
 public class Entitys {

@PrimaryKey
@NonNull
public String ID;

public  String ts;
public  String tss;

public Entitys(@NonNull String ID, String ts, String tss) {
    this.ID = ID;
    this.ts = ts;
    this.tss = tss;
}

public String getTss() {
    return tss;
}

public void setTss(String tss) {
    this.tss = tss;
}

public void setID(String ID) {
    this.ID = ID;
}

public void setTs(String ts) {
    this.ts = ts;
}

public String getID() {
    return ID;
}

public String getTs() {
    return ts;
}
 }
```

database

```
 @Database(entities = {Entitys.class}, version = 1)
 public abstract class PathwaysDB extends RoomDatabase {

private static volatile PathwaysDB INSTANCE;

public static EntityDao entityDao() {
    return null;
}

public static PathwaysDB getInstance(Context context) {
    if (INSTANCE == null) {
        synchronized (PathwaysDB.class) {
            if (INSTANCE == null) {
                INSTANCE = Room.databaseBuilder(context.getApplicationContext(),
                        PathwaysDB.class, "Pathwaysdb")
                        .build();
            }
        }
    }
    return INSTANCE;
}


 }
```

MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();
Button tb;
EditText te, tes;
String ts, tss, ID;

CompositeDisposable compositeDisposable = new CompositeDisposable();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ID ="test";
    te = findViewById(R.id.te);

    tb = findViewById(R.id.tb);
    tb.setOnClickListener(this);

    tes = findViewById(R.id.tes);

    Builddb();

    try{
    getData();}catch (Exception e){}
}

   private void Builddb() {

    Completable.fromAction(() -> PathwaysDB.getInstance(this))
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(new CompletableObserver() {
                @Override
                public void onSubscribe(Disposable d) {
                    compositeDisposable.add(d);
                }

                @Override
                public void onComplete() {
                    // action was completed successfully
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(Throwable e) {
                    // something went wrong
                }
            });
}

private void getData() {

    Maybe<List<Entitys>> single = entityDao().getEntity(ID);
    single.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(new MaybeObserver<List<Entitys>>() {
                @Override
                public void onSubscribe(Disposable d) {
                    // add it to a CompositeDisposable
                }

                @Override
                public void onSuccess(List<Entitys> entity) {
                    te.setText(entity.indexOf(ts));
                    tes.setText(entity.indexOf(tss));
                }
                @Override
                public void onError(Throwable e) {
                    // show an error message
                }

                @Override
                public void onComplete() {
                }
            });

    compositeDisposable.add((Disposable) single);
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();

    compositeDisposable.dispose();
}

private void updateUserName() {

   ts = te.getText().toString();
   tss = tes.getText().toString();
   Entitys entitys = new Entitys(ID, ts, tss);

    Completable.fromAction(() -> entityDao().insert(entitys))
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(new CompletableObserver() {
                @Override
                public void onSubscribe(Disposable d) {
                    compositeDisposable.add(d);
                }

                @Override
                public void onComplete() {
                    // action was completed successfully
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(Throwable e) {
                    // something went wrong
                }
            });


}

@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    updateUserName();

    Intent forward = new Intent(this, secondpage.class);
    startActivity(forward);
}
 }
```

Comment: `NullPointerException` becuase returning `null ` from `entityDao()`

Comment: Please do not edit your questions into answers. I have rolled this back to revision #2, which was the last good question state. A self-answer would be very welcome from you - you can see the text of your answer material [in the revision history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/59549976/revisions).

Answer (score 0):

Reason for crash is this line in your **PathwaysDB** class

```
public static EntityDao entityDao() {
return null;
}
```

it is returning null. It should be like

```
public abstract EntityDao entityDao()
```

Comment: Thank you for the help. If I change the code as suggested I can't compile. The following error error: cannot find symbol method entityDao() what should method entityDao() be?

Comment: The issue is here  Maybe<List<Entitys>> single = entityDao().getEntity(ID); and  Completable.fromAction(() -> entityDao().insert(entitys))  I have tried to put the database in front as PathwaysDB.entityDao() but it tells me a non static method can't be can't be referenced from static context.

Comment: you have to use your class instance i.e you can use PathwaysDb.getInstance(context).entityDao(). and also you have to use correct context. In activity you can use activity context.

Comment: I think it was the getApplicationContext() that was missing as I no longer get that error and the app moves on. thank you. I had been putting in this. and class.this.  I still have a problem with the data coming back to fill the fields though. I will post a gain later I'm gonna try to worth though it for a bit

Comment: I figured out the last part changing code above. Thank you both for your time and effort. I appreciate you helping me learn.

Answer (score 0):

You forget to add @Dao annonation to your EntityDao interface class.
also you need to change below method :

```
public static EntityDao entityDao() {
    return null;
}
```

To

```
public abstract EntityDao entityDao();
```

Comment: @dao is at the top, it's just not pictured here i forgot the cut and past it is there though

Comment: have you tried rebuild your project after adding above abstract method?

Comment: yeah I've tried it. nothing. I might just wipe this whole thing and start over again. There is something off. I have read in one place that putting the database in a singleton to make sure there is only one instance of it. But all these tutorials don't do that.

Comment: please provide answer with explanation.